# Submit form on same page and echo records from database

Tags: php, forms, get

I'm trying to submit the form and echo the data from the MySQL table on the same page, but it doesn't show anything, I think I have something wrong in my code, but I don't know what it is.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
if ( isset($_POST['consulta']) )
{
    echo"
            <table align='center' border='1' class='TablaConsulta'>
                <tr>;
                    <td>Codigo Escaneado</td>
                    <td>Nombre Producto</td>
                    <td>Precio Prodcuto</td>
                </tr>
    ";
        include ("connector.php");
        $con = conectar();
        $tbl = "productos";
        $query = "SELECT * FROM $tbl WHERE  CodigoProducto =".$_POST['CoProducto'];
        $resultado = mysql_query($query, $con) or die(mysql_error($con));   
        while($dato=mysql_fetch_array($resultado)){
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".$dato['CodigoProducto']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$dato['Descripcion']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$dato['Precio']."</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
        }

        mysql_close($con);//cerrar conexion
    echo"</table>";

}
?>
```

Comment: is `$_POST['CoProducto']` an integer?

Comment: Please print the $query variable and run it against the database through terminal/phpmyadmin. Let me know if it works fine.

Comment: Don't ever use `mysql_*` functions! Use `mysqli_*` functions or `PDO`. This is serious security issue. And as of PHP 5.6.0, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Just fixed the problem by myself, I was using mysqli on the "connector.php" segment, and mysql on the query segment.

I changed my code to this:

```
<?php
if ( isset($_POST['consulta']) )
{
    echo"
            <table align='center' border='1' class='TablaConsulta'>
                <tr>;
                    <td>Codigo Escaneado</td>
                    <td>Nombre Producto</td>
                    <td>Precio Prodcuto</td>
                </tr>
    ";
        include ("connector.php");
        $con = conectar();
        $tbl = "productos";
        $query = "SELECT * FROM $tbl WHERE  CodigoProducto =".$_POST['CoProducto'];
        echo $query;
        $resultado = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysqli_error($con));  
        while($dato=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".$dato['CodigoProducto']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$dato['Descripcion']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$dato['Precio']."</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
        }

        mysql_close($con);//cerrar conexion
    echo"</table>";

}
```

?>

And it's now working.

Comment: you are still using `mysql_close`, you might want to change that

Comment: Try going with "find&replace" through all your files to replace `mysql_` with `mysqli_` to be 100% sure :)